# KeyboardInterrupt won't work even though condition is demonstrably met

Tags: python, error-handling, pynput

I'm printing the following when a user presses on the keyboard arrows:

```
You picked left! 
You picked left! 
You picked right!
```

When the user presses escape, `KeyboardInterrupt` is supposed to be raised *right after* printing `You pressed escape!`, but it doesn't. `You pressed escape!` is printed but that's it. The same behavior occurs in JupyterLab and PyCharm.

**Why isn't KeyboardInterrupt raised?**

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

class CoolTrick:

    @staticmethod
    def _on_press(key):

        if key == Key.left:
            print('\rYou picked left!',             end='       ')

        if key == Key.right:
            print('\rYou picked right!',            end='       ')

        if key == Key.esc:
            print('\rYou pressed escape!',          end='       ')

            raise KeyboardInterrupt('You interrupted the process by'
                                    'pressing escape.')

    def run(self):
        while True:
            while True:

                with Listener(
                        on_press=self._on_press) as listener:
                    listener.join()

ct = CoolTrick()

ct.run()
```

```
You pressed escape! 
You picked right!
```

Comment: If you run it outside of an IDE, does it work? How about if you use `raise SystemExit` instead? (`SystemExit` is probably more correct in the end either way, but finding out why `KeyboardInterrupt` doesn’t work is worth doing.)

Comment: You could also check to make sure the exception is reraised at `join`: `try:` `listener.join()` `except e:` `print("got some kind of exception")` `raise`